# difference between the corona sdk 2013 version (2013.1137.msi) and 2014 version(2014.2189.msi)

Tags: lua, coronasdk

i'm using corona sdk 2013 version. my installer package is **CoronaSDK-2013.1137.msi**, i have no problem when using it **BUT when i change my corona SDK to CORONA SDK 2014 version (2014.2189.msi),** i have bugs like **setReferencePoint error** and other things so i change back my corona sdk to 2013 version because it will comsumes time when

my question is:

even if my corona sdk is outdated, my apk package will be still uploaded in the google play?

Comment: why aren't you using 2013.2100?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The biggest problem you ar facing betweet  1137 and 2189 is that anything over 2000 using the new Graphics 2.0 library.  You have two options:

In your `config.lua` you can add this parameter:

```
application =
{
    content =
    {
        graphicsCompatibility = 1,  -- Turn on V1 Compatibility Mode

        width = 320,
        height = 480,
        scale = "letterbox"
    },
}
```

Your mileage with the graphics compatibility flag will vary.  I didn't have the greatest results with it so I spent the time to upgrade my code to Graphics 2.0.   Here's the [migration guide here](http://docs.coronalabs.com/guide/graphics/migration_g20.html).

Comment: thanks. i will spend time to upgrade my code to graphics 2.0. :)